# How to know wheter the given identifier is Stored procedure or Table or View

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

Is there anyway to know whether the given identifier is a table or view or a procedure, etc... in oracle?

Example: I have an identifer "PICKUPON", I want to know the object type of this identifier. I took few mins to know it is procedure by browsing in Schema browser in Toad. Is there any query to get this job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, you have the system views ALL_OBJECTS, DBA_OBJECTS, USER_OBJECTS  which enable you to query the database schema.

You can query them just like a table, as in

```
SELECT OBJECT_TYPE FROM ALL_OBJECTS where OBJECT_NAME = '...'
```

Note that the tree views are a little different, and the results depemnd on the priveleges of user DB user:

- USER_OBJECTS shows the current user objects.
- ALL_OBJECTS shows all objects of current and those object which you have rights to access.
- DBA_OBJECTS shows all object of all users .

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Oracle database to work with but could you use the OBJECT_TYPE column from this?

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2005.htm#i1583352

Answer (score 0):

You can check against `all_objects` and look in the `object_type` column like

```
select *
  from all_objects 
 where object_name like '%PICKUPON%'
```